# need a REGEX for not allowing a % after a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i want a regular expression for not allowing a number/digit before           %(percentage) special character or vice versa , a % should not come after a number. I am already using a regular expression as follows. the problem is this thing/logic should also include in the following expression. help will be thanked.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.*[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/
```

Comment: FYI, your `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.*[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/` is equal to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.*)$/`. Not sure what you need to match, sorry, but try `/^(?!.*(?:\d%|%\d))[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.*)$/`

Comment: You can negate a match condition using "^". ([0-9]*[^%])